# delegate 'Create all child objects' permission in OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ou

I am using below script to delegate 'Create all child objects'  permission in OU. It is working fine but Inheritance Type is getting set to  'This Object only'. How Can I set the Inheritance Type to 'This Object and all descendent Objects'.

```
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.CreateChildAccessRule $s,"ALLOW"))
```

I have tried below overloads but none seem to work:

```
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.CreateChildAccessRule $s,"ALLOW",'SelfAndChildren',([GUID]("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")).guid))


$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.CreateChildAccessRule $s,"ALLOW",'All'))
```

Comment: Are you writing the ACL back to the object using `Set-Acl`?

Comment: @Gabriel Yes . It adding permission to ou after that only

Comment: What happens when you use `$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.CreateChildAccessRule $s,"ALLOW",'All'))`?

Comment: It sets the inheritance type as 'Special'.